# load data into mysql from restful web services

Tags: mysql, rest

I want to load some data into mysql from a restful web services.

The API accepts http requests and returns xml output.

I want to load the xml output into mysql.

How can I do this ?

Comment: simple, make webservice call and insert to database! without showing your effort of coding we can't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I see you would like to do two steps in one ;) First that you should do, creating a Java object from XML (unmarshalling) and 2nd, save the object to DB.

For 1st, you can use JAXB or other free tool. For 2nd, use Hibernate ;)

Comment: Does this tool also help in fetching the xml output from the restful API?

Comment: Yep, it can help. You can download from maven repo. And for using, you need to create a XSD file in that you describe the XML structure. My team use it in many projects but mainly for SOAP.

But there are a lots of other solution. Do you use JSON in the restful webservice?